# Setting Up a Dynamic jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting this code to work. What I'm attempting to do is show one div based on the given ID from the click and hide all the rest. All of the divs have the same class. This is the logic as I perceive it:

1. div.slide AND div#slide1 (ID is dynamic based on the click) show div#slide1
2. div.slide AND NOT div#slide1 hide div.slide

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure if I'm setting up the slideId variable correctly or passing the data correctly:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slide1Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide1' }, scroller);
    $("#slide2Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide2' }, scroller);
    $("#slide3Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide3' }, scroller);
    $("#slide4Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide4' }, scroller);
    $("#slide5Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide5' }, scroller);
    $("#slide6Nav").bind('click', { id: '#slide6' }, scroller);

    function scroller(event){
        var scrollYPos = $(event.data.id).offset().top;
        var slideId = $(event.data.id);
        event.preventDefault();
        TweenMax.to(".slide",.5, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeOut, onComplete:function() {
            $(slideId).css('display', 'block');
            $('div.slide:not(slideId)').css('display', 'none');
            console.log(slideId);
        }});
        TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{y:scrollYPos, x:0}, ease:Power4.easeOut, delay:.5});
        TweenMax.to(".slide",2, {opacity:100, ease:Power4.easeOut, delay:1});

    }

});
```

Comment: I believe `slideId` would return a jQuery object.. therefore `div.slide:not(slideId)` is not a valid selector

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jQuery, you can use in place of:

```
$(slideId).css('display', 'block');
$('div.slide:not(slideId)').css('display', 'none');
```

use this instead:

```
$(slideId).show();
$('div.slide:not(slideId)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$(slideId).css('display', 'block');
$('div.slide:not(slideId)').css('display', 'none');
```

to

```
$(slideId).show();
$('div.slide:not(' + slideId + ')').hide();
```

also thank to jf for pointing the id